# can't access data for dropdown list

Tags: laravel, drop-down-menu

Need to get the machines data in machines table in the database to insert the projectmachines table. m_id is a foreignkey in projectmachines table and shows the error as machines as `undefined variable`

```
<select class="form-control" name="pm_mid" data-parsley-required="true">>
 @foreach($machines as $c)
    <option value="{{ $c->m_id }}">{{ $c->$m_id }}</option>
 @endforeach
</select>
```

Comment: Attach your controller code and your model also

Comment: public function create()
    {
    
        return view('dashboard.projects.add_machinestoproject');
    }

Comment: <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class projectmachines extends Model
{
    //
}

Comment: You didn't add $machine variable to your view in controller

Comment: Could you please give me the code for that